# how do I bring back the initial menu to configure a mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

I hope this is easy: how do I bring back the Math Function menu for a mesh once it has been initially created?  After I first configure the function the menu disappears and I can't seem to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

The math function menu like all object initialization menus can only be used when you create an object, if you go to edit mode or use any operation in the 3D view port, it will disappear.